# How to edit and debug OAF java code in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea, oracle-adf, jdeveloper, oaf

I agree that JDeveloper provides some unique ADF-specific functionality, but when it comes to work with java code, IntelliJ IDEA works better for me. Can I move java-related operations to IDEA?

Answer (score 0):

**Setup**

1. Create IDEA project from existing sources, setup source folders and connect libraries.

[image: IDEA project from existing sources]
[image: IDEA project module]
[image: IDEA project libs]

2. Setup IDEA run configuration. "Listen to remote JWM" means that IDEA will act as a server and Jdev will connect to it as soon as it starts running. It is good if you need to debug processRequest() method - debugger must be connected immediately. I chose "JDK 1.4.x" because it looks closer to VM parameters which Jdev uses when it starts debugging (you can look at those is Jdev log while debugging).

[image: IDEA run config]

3. Setup Jdev as a client. Append VM options from IDEA to your existing options.

[image: Jdev run config]

**Running**

To start debugging, first, run IDEA run configuration with green **bug** button, and second, run Jdev with green **play** button.